# Public key credentials are not accessible among subdomains during web authentication

Tags: webauthn

I was able to create public-private key pair using web authentication in the browser for a domain "www.exxample.ba" but i am not able to access the credentials using get() from "www.example.co.in".

Is there any way to get past this limitation like using an extension or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is no, the API itself fundamentally prevents your use case from being possible.

Digging into it a bit, WebAuthn credentials are bound to an [RP ID](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#rp-id) that is the "effective domain" of a single website. The rules are fairly straightforward:

- Credentials bound to RP ID "example.com" can be used to authenticate on https://example.com and https://subdomain.example.com
- Credentials bound to "subdomain.example.com" can be used on https://subdomain.example.com but NOT on https://example.com/
- Credentials bound to "example.com" CANNOT be used on https://example.org